# Foreign Key Field will not update upon Db.savechanges()

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an incident model :

```
public class Incident
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ResolvedAt { get; set; }
}
```

and priority model :

```
public class Priority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

which share a foreign key relationship. 
The Priority table has 10 fixed priorities from P0 to P9.

Here is the HttpPost after editing in the View.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Incident incident)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (incident.Id == 0)
                db.Incidents.Add(incident);
            else
            {
                db.Incidents.Attach(incident);
                db.Entry(incident).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(incident);
    }
```

While debugging I can see everything updates inside the `incident`. 
But the changes are not reflected for the Priority after `savechanges()` (which has the foreign key relationship)
Why is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure would work if you had an additional foreign key property `public int PriorityId { get; set; }` in the `Incident` model (or use `int?` as type if `Incident.Priority` is optional). You would then bind `Incident.PriorityId` to your view (a combobox?) instead of `Incident.Priority.Id`.

If you don't want a foreign key property and stick with your model as is the Edit action will be a bit more complex, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Incident incident)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Priorities.Attach(incident.Priority);
        if (incident.Id == 0)
            db.Incidents.Add(incident);
        else
        {
            var incidentInDb = db.Incidents.Include(i => i.Priority)
                .SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == incident.Id);
            if (incidentInDb != null)
            {
                db.Entry(incidentInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(incident);
                incidentInDb.Priority = incident.Priority;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(incident);
}
```

Generally setting the `Modified` state on an entity won't set this state for relationships (unless you have a foreign key property in your model, see first paragraph). That's the reason why your original code doesn't work and the additional line `incidentInDb.Priority = incident.Priority` is necessary. Change tracking will recognize if the priority did change and then update the foreign key in the database.